# iOS7:Posting image to server leads to error HTTP Status 406

Tags: ios, spring, uiimage, multipartform-data, nsurlrequest

When i am trying to post image to server i'm getting an error

"The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers ()."

Here is the code that i am using to upload image

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backGb.png"];
 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 NSMutableData *bodyData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];// backGb.jpg
 [bodyData appendData:[@"pic" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 [bodyData appendData:UIImagePNGRepresentation((UIImage *)image)];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
  [request setValue:@"application/xml" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
 [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];
 connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

server team asked me to use "use file as parameter 'pic' "

I appreciate for any help.

Comment: Why `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pic"]`, just use `@"pic"`. Best to spend some time learning the basics of Objective-C.

Comment: That is not the way to pass data as a parameter. Check the links on the right for how to do that.

Comment: @Zaph Can you tell me how to pass parameter ?

Comment: Consider using AFNetworking, it is a higher level framework.